# spring boot multiple database configuration with microsoft sql server

Tags: javascript, sql-server, spring, spring-boot

i've multiple databases under a single sql server database. 
from application.properties file. i've configured to default schema in springboot.
now i would like to chage to another database with same url, usrname, pawd.

how can i changedo this ? when i give annotation over class with

```
@table (name = db2.dbo.tname)
```

it throws error saying,

> unable to map this dboject in database 1

here's my configuration:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=testdb;integratedSecurity=false;

spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=myPassword
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection
spring.datasource.initialize=true
```

my application works with the default db i gave on application properties. but i've to connect to another database.
how can i resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the regular spring properties to do that. Here's an example on how you can connect to TWO databases (Or more if you need):

First you have to disable the autoconfiguration that picks up just one DB:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class, DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class})
```

And now you just have to provide your own configuration for JPA and Datasources:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "ds1EntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "ds1TransactionManager",
        basePackageClasses = Ds1Repository.class)
public class DataSource1Config {

    @Bean
    PlatformTransactionManager ds1TransactionManager() {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(tfccgEntityManagerFactory().getObject());
    }

    @Bean
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean ds1EntityManagerFactory() {

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

        factoryBean.setDataSource(ds1());
        factoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        factoryBean.setPackagesToScan(Ds1Entity.class.getPackage().getName());
        factoryBean.getJpaPropertyMap().put("hibernate.dialect", dialect);
        factoryBean.getJpaPropertyMap().put("hibernate.show_sql", showSQL);
        factoryBean.getJpaPropertyMap().put("hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers", quoteIdentifiers);

        return factoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    DataSource ds1() {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setUrl(url);
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(driverClass);
        dataSource.setUsername(username);
        dataSource.setPassword(password);
        dataSource.setTestOnBorrow(testOnBorrow);
        dataSource.setMaxTotal(maxTotal);
        dataSource.setInitialSize(initialSize);
        dataSource.setMaxIdle(maxIdle);
        return dataSource;
    }
}
```

You can have a copy of this class for a `ds2` datasource on which you'll have a second set of `transactionManager` `entityManagerFactory` and `datasource` and on which you'll enable JPA Repositories and Entity scan for different packages and name the beans with different names.

Then, If you need transaction isolation in a method you'll have to provide the `transactionManager` name since you'd have 2:

`@Transactional(transactionManager = "ds1TransactionManager")`

Comment: In the datasource url